# Why instanceof keyword does not work with Backbone js models?

Tags: javascript, oop, backbone.js

I am building a Backbone JS application that involves inheritance and the use of instanceof javascript keyword.

I have the following code :

```
app.Sport = Backbone.Model.extend
({
    defaults:
    {
        id: 0,
        title: 'Running'
    }
});
```

Further in the code, I instantiate a new Sport by typing :

```
var newSport = new app.Sport ();
```

I may manipulate this newly created instance without issues.

But, because there's a but, the instanceof keyword always return false when asking for the type of my instance :

```
console.log ('is newSport a Sport instance ? ' + newSport instanceof app.Sport);
```

always display false. Why ?

Note : I did not mention inheritance in my question, as it does not even work with the simple form of OOP (one instance of the base class, and asking for the type just after).

My initial purpose is to trigger specific action depending on the type of the sport (thus the use of instanceof keyword) ; it could be a cool one, or an extreme one :

```
app.CoolSport = app.Sport.extend ({ ... });
app.ExtremeSport = app.Sport.extend ({ ... });
```

---

**EDIT** : I isolated the issue. It is not linked to instanceof keyword or the Model I declared. Rather, I populate a Backbone collection, and push to it some different kind of sports. Here is the test code : ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jerome7/krRQV/4/))

```
var app = {};


app.Sport = Backbone.Model.extend
({
    defaults:
    {
        id: 0,
        title: 'Running'
    }
});


app.CoolSport = app.Sport.extend
({
    defaults:
    {
        uselessAttr:'I am a Cool Sport !'
    }
});



app.SportList = Backbone.Collection.extend
({
    model: app.Sport

});


var coolSport1 = new app.CoolSport();

console.log ('is coolSport1 a Sport instance ? ' , coolSport1 instanceof app.Sport);

console.log ('is coolSport1 a CoolSport instance ? ' , coolSport1 instanceof app.CoolSport);

console.log ('is coolSport1 a CoolSport instance (wrong operand in console) ? ' + coolSport1 instanceof app.CoolSport);


var sportList = new app.SportList();
sportList.push (coolSport1.toJSON());


sportList.each ( function ( sport )
{
    if ( sport instanceof app.CoolSport )
    {
        console.log ( "sport is an instance of Cool Sport ! Yeah !" , sport instanceof app.CoolSport ) ;
    }                       
    else
    {
        console.log ( "Not a CoolSport instance..");
    }
});
```

And guess what ? my CoolSport instance... is not a CoolSport instance. I suspect the init of the Backbone SportList collection to be the issue.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/dX7Nz/

Comment: I a fiddle to reproduce your problem, but my tests show this should work as expected. Which version of backbone/underscore are you on? (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HHS8u/)

Comment: try write down console.log ('is newSport a Sport instance ? ', (newSport instanceof app.Sport)); - you get instanceof `'is newSport a Sport instance ? + newSport` - it's will be a string

Comment: Same for me : it is working on jsfiddle. It is not version issue. Please see my updated question (issue is related to collection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution :-)

I commented the code below :

```
var coolSport1 = new app.CoolSport();

// Of course it is
console.log ('is coolSport1 a Sport instance ? ' , coolSport1 instanceof app.Sport);

console.log ('is coolSport1 a CoolSport instance ? ' , coolSport1 instanceof app.CoolSport);


var sportList = new app.SportList();

// Here is the tricky part : we push the JSON representation of our CoolSport instance
sportList.push (coolSport1.toJSON());


// Backbone does not know anymore the subtype of our instance, as it has been JSON stringified juste before.
sportList.each ( function ( sport )
{
    if ( sport instanceof app.CoolSport )
    {
        console.log ( "sport is an instance of Cool Sport ! Yeah !" , sport instanceof app.CoolSport ) ;
    }                       
    else
    {
        console.log ( "Not a CoolSport instance..");
    }
});
```

Backbone documentation provides a mechanism for this behaviour :

```
var Library = Backbone.Collection.extend({

  model: function(attrs, options) {
    if (condition) {
      return new PublicDocument(attrs, options);
    } else {
      return new PrivateDocument(attrs, options);
    }
  }

});
```

It tells the collection how to process a JSON representation, in order to add a correct subtype instance to the list. So, to add a CoolSport while keeping the code untouched, one just need to add the model function in the SportList collection, and returning a new CoolSport if it contains 'uselessAttr' (see the code in my question).

I took a different way, and directly pass a CoolSport instance through add() method of the collection, thus preserving its subtype.

Thanks everybody for help, and hope my answer will help others :-)

Answer (score 5):

Please, do not this:

```
console.log ('is newSport a Sport instance ? ' + newSport instanceof app.Sport);
```

Do it right:

```
console.log ('is newSport a Sport instance ? ' + (newSport instanceof app.Sport));
```

or

```
console.log ('is newSport a Sport instance ? ', newSport instanceof app.Sport);
```

Comment: I will never ever do it the bad way. Thanks for pointing me out this mistake. Please see my updated question, as it states the real issue I have.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the model in your collection as 'app.Sport'

so when you are pushing coolSport1.toJSON(), it will be initialized by using app.Sport model

that's why it's not a CoolSport instance but a Sport instance instead.

Comment: I found the same some minutes before you (see my answer just below), and indeed it was the right solution. And glad you were there if I didn't find it by myself ;-)